# Comparing 2 SQL Query Result from 2 different Tables

Tags: sql

Can someone point me in the right direction what I should be doing to compare the result of these two queries?

I want to know if the results are IDENTICAL to each other

I'm Planning to create an SP that will determine first if the result of the 2 queries are the same before inserting it an a table.

Query 1:

```
SELECT TOP 10 
    EventName, EventDate 
FROM 
    EventTBL 
WHERE 
    EventType ='Bday' 
    AND EventDate >= getdate() -30
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT 
    (Ename + ' ' + Lname), 
    DATEADD(YY, DATEPART(YYYY, GETDATE()) - 
    DATEPART(YYYY,dateOfBirth), dateOfBirth) 
FROM 
    EmpTBL 
WHERE 
    DATEADD(Year, DATEPART(Year, GETDATE()) - 
         DATEPART( Year, DateOfBirth), DateOfBirth)  
    BETWEEN CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()) 
        AND CONVERT( DATE, GETDATE() + 30)
```

Comment: Tag dbms used. (Some non-ANSI SQL there...)

Comment: What kind of comparison ? Emp name wise ? can you post results .

Comment: The easiest way to compare sets is using set operations, e.g. `SELECT #1 EXCEPT SELECT #2` results in an empty set if all rows in `SELECT #2` also exist in `SELECT #1`.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you build one SQL where you join both tables, and according to the result perform the action you want.

Example:

```
SELECT 
    event.EventName as eName, event.EventDate as eDate, 
    emp.Ename + ' ' + emp.Lname as empName, emp.empdateOfBirth as empBirth
FROM 
    EventTBL event INNER JOIN EmpTBL emp ON event.pk = emp.fk
```

If the two tables are not joined you could join on some other fields

```
SELECT 
    event.EventName as eventName, event.EventDate as eventDate, 
    emp.Ename + ' ' + emp.Lname as empName, emp.empdateOfBirth as empBirth
FROM 
    EventTBL event INNER JOIN EmpTBL emp ON evnt.eventDate = emp.empBirth
```

You can also use DATEADD / DATEDIFF on the date fields to make some special date comparison. Remember to index these date-fields to optimize the join operation.

Add WHERE clause and perhaps additional clause for the join and you get the result you are looking for.

Use your DBMS SQL-syntax for building this into a insert if you want to store the result. It could be: INSERT INTO - SELECT FROM, SELECT - INTO - FROM or another insert SQL syntax depending on your needs and DBMS. If the result from the query results in no rows, no insert will happen.